# Oracle - Insert New Row with Auto Incremental ID

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a workqueue table that has a workid column. The workID column has values that increment automatically. Is there a way I can run a query in the backend to insert a new row and have the workID column increment automatically?
When I try to insert a null, it throws error ORA01400 - Cannot insert null into workid.

```
insert into WORKQUEUE  (facilitycode,workaction,description) values ('J', 'II',    'TESTVALUES')
```

What I have tried so far - I tried to look at the table details and didn't see any auto-increment. The table script is as follow

```
"WORKID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

Database: Oracle 10g

Screenshot of some existing data.
[image]

---

**ANSWER:**

I have to thank each and everyone for the help. Today was a great learning experience and without your support, I couldn't have done. Bottom line is, I was trying to insert a row into a table that already has sequences and triggers. All I had to do was find the right sequence, for my question, and call that sequence into my query.

The links you all provided me helped me look these sequences up and find the one that is for this workid column. Thanks to you all, I gave everyone a thumbs up, I am able to tackle another dragon today and help patient care take a step forward!"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle - Modify an existing table to auto-increment a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681122/oracle-modify-an-existing-table-to-auto-increment-a-column)

Comment: @Li0liQ - No I am not trying to modify the table at all. I simply want to insert a new row in the existing table the way it is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get an auto increment number you need to use a sequence in Oracle.
(See [here](http://psoug.org/reference/sequences.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm)).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;

SELECT my_seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; -- to get the next value

-- use in a trigger for your table demo
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER demo_increment 
BEFORE INSERT ON demo
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT my_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: can you please answer my question? I dont have enough reputations to answer my question and close it. Please copy and paste this gratitude below:"Thank you one and all." For my solution, please look under my question."

Answer (score 29):

This is a simple way to do it without any triggers or sequences:

```
insert into WORKQUEUE (ID, facilitycode, workaction, description)
  values ((select max(ID)+1 from WORKQUEUE), 'J', 'II', 'TESTVALUES')
```

It worked for me but would not work with an empty table, I guess.

Comment: Perfect for a non empty table, don't need to deal with triggers or sequences with that approach.

Comment: This is great for me because I don't have access to create a sequence. I changed my first insert to set the ID to 1 and it worked perfect.

Comment: for empty tables you can use nvl(max(id), 0) + 1 which transforms null values into the number you pass as an argument

Answer (score 19):

There is no built-in auto_increment in Oracle.

You need to use `sequences` and `triggers`.

Read [**here**](http://earlruby.org/2009/01/creating-auto-increment-columns-in-oracle/) how to do it right. (Step-by-step how-to for "Creating auto-increment columns in Oracle")

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `SEQUENCE` or `TRIGGER` to increment automatically the value of a given column in your database table however the use of `TRIGGERS` would be more appropriate. See the following documentation of Oracle that contains major clauses used with triggers with suitable examples.

> Use the CREATE TRIGGER statement to create and enable a database trigger, which is:
>
> - A stored PL/SQL block associated with a table, a schema, or the
>     database or
> - An anonymous PL/SQL block or a call to a procedure implemented in
>     PL/SQL or Java
>
> Oracle Database automatically executes a trigger when specified conditions occur. [See](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm).

---

Following is a simple `TRIGGER` just as an example for you that inserts the primary key value in a specified table based on the *maximum value* of that column. You can modify the schema name, table name etc and use it. Just give it a try.

```
/*Create a database trigger that generates automatically primary key values on the CITY table using the max function.*/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROJECT.PK_MAX_TRIGGER_CITY
BEFORE INSERT ON PROJECT.CITY
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    CNT NUMBER;
    PKV CITY.CITY_ID%TYPE;
    NO NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)INTO CNT FROM CITY;

    IF CNT=0 THEN
        PKV:='CT0001';
    ELSE
        SELECT 'CT'||LPAD(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CITY_ID,3,LENGTH(CITY_ID)))+1),4,'0') INTO PKV
        FROM CITY;
    END IF; 
    :NEW.CITY_ID:=PKV;
END;
```

Would automatically generates values such as `CT0001`, `CT0002`, `CT0002` and so on and inserts into the given column of the specified table.

Answer (score 3):

```
ELXAN@DB1> create table cedvel(id integer,ad varchar2(15));

Table created.

ELXAN@DB1> alter table cedvel add constraint pk_ad primary key(id);

Table altered.

ELXAN@DB1> create sequence test_seq start with 1 increment by 1;

Sequence created.

ELXAN@DB1> create or replace trigger ad_insert
before insert on cedvel
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row
begin
    select test_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8 

Trigger created.

ELXAN@DB1> insert into cedvel (ad) values ('nese');

1 row created.
```

Answer (score 2):

the complete know how, i have included a example of the triggers and sequence

```
create table temasforo(
idtemasforo NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
autor       VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
fecha       DATE DEFAULT (sysdate),
asunto      LONG  );

create sequence temasforo_seq
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  nomaxvalue;

create or replace
trigger temasforo_trigger
  before insert on temasforo
  referencing OLD as old NEW as new
  for each row
  begin
      :new.idtemasforo:=temasforo_seq.nextval;
    end;
```

reference:
http://thenullpointerexceptionx.blogspot.mx/2013/06/llaves-primarias-auto-incrementales-en.html

Comment: Should "idtemasfor" be "idtemasforo" in the second line?

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL trigger for automatic date generation in oracle table:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER name_of_trigger

BEFORE INSERT

ON table_name

REFERENCING NEW AS NEW

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SELECT sysdate INTO :NEW.column_name FROM dual;

END;
```

/

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I'll mention that Oracle 12c does support this feature.  Also it's supposedly faster than the triggers approach.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
  (
    id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
    START WITH 1 NOCACHE ORDER ) NOT NULL ,
    name       VARCHAR2 (50)
  )
  LOGGING ;
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_PK PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Best approach: Get the next value from sequence

The nicest approach is getting the `NEXTVAL` from the `SEQUENCE` "associated" with the table. Since **the sequence is not directly associated to any specific table**,
we will need to manually refer the corresponding table from the sequence name convention.

The sequence name used on a table, if follow the sequence naming convention, will mention the table name inside its name. Something likes `<table_name>_SEQ`. You will immediately recognize it the moment you see it.

First, check within Oracle system if there is any sequence "associated" to the table

```sql
SELECT * FROM all_sequences
WHERE SEQUENCE_OWNER = '<schema_name>';
```

will present something like this
[image: sample_sequence_query_output]

Grab that `SEQUENCE_NAME` and evaluate the `NEXTVAL` of it in your `INSERT` query

```sql
INSERT INTO workqueue(id, value) VALUES (workqueue_seq.NEXTVAL, 'A new value...')
```

**Additional tip**

In case you're unsure if this sequence is actually associated with the table, just quickly compare the `LAST_NUMBER` of the sequence (meaning the current value) with the maximum id of
that table. It's expected that the `LAST_NUMBER` is greater than or equals to the current maximum id value in the table, as long as the gap is not too suspiciously large.

```sql
SELECT LAST_NUMBER
FROM all_sequences
WHERE SEQUENCE_OWNER = '<schema_name>' AND SEQUENCE_NAME = 'workqueue_seq';

SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM workqueue;
```

*Reference*: [Oracle CURRVAL and NEXTVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/server.816/a76989/ch26.htm)

#### Alternative approach: Get the current max id from the table

The alternative approach is getting the max value from the table, please refer to [Zsolt Sky answer in this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153232/5668956)

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple way to do it without any triggers or sequences:

insert into WORKQUEUE (ID, facilitycode, workaction, description)
  values ((select count(1)+1 from WORKQUEUE), 'J', 'II', 'TESTVALUES');

Note : here need to use count(1) in place of max(id) column

It perfectly works for an empty table also.

Comment: If the value of an already created id is greater than the rows number, at some point this solution will not work. Example: 6 rows with IDs starting with value 7.