# Auto increment alternatives in oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, auto-increment

I am relatively new to Oracle and have been browsing the web for the past few hours and still cannot find a definitive answer to a question thats been bugging me.

I am from a software engineering background and the amount of code repetition I am doing by creating AI sequences for each table is frustrating me. Is there anyway I can define an AI function which takes the name of the sequence and table so I could just call the function in my trigger, or do I need to hard code each sequence?

I currently have a sequence like this for each of the 12 tables I have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_site_addr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON site_addr FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF INSERTING THEN
    IF :NEW.site_addr_id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT seq_site_addr_id.nextval
        INTO :NEW.site_addr_id
        FROM sys.dual;
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

Ideally I would like to be able to do the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_site_addr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON site_addr FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF INSERTING THEN
    IF :NEW.site_addr_id IS NULL THEN
        -- Param 1 = sequence name, Parm 2 = table name
        auto_increment(seq_site_addr_id, site_addr);
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

How would I go about doing this, any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Alex.

*** EDIT ***
To clear up any confusion, I'd like to create a function, but I don't know if it is possible to embed a sequence within a function and then use the parameters i.e.

```
CREATE FUNCTION auto_increment( seq_name, table_col_id)
       SELECT seq_name.nextval
       INTO :NEW.table_col_id
       FROM sys.dual;
END;
```

That way it would dynamically create increment sequences within the trigger for each table without me having to hard code the AI trigger on each table.

If this isn't possible then hard coding it is no big deal, it was just a query I had.

Comment: Have you tried an actual `SEQUENCE`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681122/oracle-modify-an-existing-table-to-auto-increment-a-column and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

Comment: So you want to create something like a for loop ?

Comment: updating question real quick.

Comment: @admdrew the sequences already exist, I should have specified that, I want to pass the sequence to a function and then increment its current value.

Comment: So you want to replace 1 line of code to using a function that passes the same values? I don't see any benefit...

Comment: The reason I want to have this function is so I can reuse it elsewhere in my code - like I said I have 12 tables and the system could grow.  
I understand your point I just wondered if this was possible, I may be thinking too similarly from a Java or C perspective where its good practice to modularise code as much as possible.

Comment: Upgrade to 12c (if you can) and make use of [identity columns](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php)

Comment: Why not use the same sequence for all the tables?

Comment: The "Oracle" way is to call your sequence directly in the `INSERT` statement: `insert into mytable (id, ... ) values (myseq.nextval, ...)`. Personally I find that much, much better than autoincrement columns. And triggers stink, I would not use them unless I have no saner choice...

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, as I stated above I am new to Oracle and I think I got confused over the concept of the sequence, I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach will be having a table to store other tables ID's.
Like:
[image: identification holder]

For any table of the application (like customer table) we will need to do some thing like this:

```
insert into ID_Table (table_name, current_id) values ('CUSTOMER', 0);
```

The function to fetch the new id will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fetch_new_id(p_table_name Varchar2) return number
IS
   result_value number;
BEGIN    
       SELECT ID_Tbale.current_id + 1
       INTO result_value 
       FROM ID_Table where trim(upper(ID_Table.table_name)) = trim(upper(p_table_name))
      for update;

      UPDATE ID_Tbale set current_id =  current_id + 1
      where trim(upper(ID_Table.table_name)) = trim(upper(p_table_name));

      COMMIT;

      RETURN result_value ;
      -- exception handling, etc
END;
```

Comment: If you are going this route, I think it is cleaner to use a single update with `RETURNING`: `update id_table set current_id = current_id + 1 where table_name = p_table_name returning current_id into result_value`

Comment: @gpeche I used `for update` intentionally to maintain concurrency and preventing lost updates.

Comment: @Moshen Yedari I know, my point was that it is cleaner if you do it all in a single `UPDATE ... RETURNING ...`, which also maintains concurrency and prevents lost updates by virtue of being a single SQL statement.

Comment: This answer makes me physically ill.

Comment: @clever-idea-widgetry Lets think about how a sequence is internally implemented by Oracle? or think about a DB that doesn't support auto incremental concept. What will be your solution?

Comment: @MohsenHeydari - Sure. Let’s. This answer seems prone to concurrency-related exceptions in a scaled up environment. The commit in the function is also a horror-show waiting to happen as well. Oracle sequences and identity columns in any platform that has them handle the concurrency aspect by forcing all consumers through a single serialized access to their values and all within an implicit autonomous transaction which this answer is both not doing. This answer if implemented would be a very badly behaved application.

Comment: agree with Michael O'Neill, the commit inside the function is a no-go, since if you execute this as part of transaction, this will effectively terminate it and create all sorts of horrible mix-ups

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend it, but something like this should do more or less what you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION auto_increment(seq_name in varchar2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  next_seq number;
BEGIN
   -- WARNING: use with care, possible SQL injections?
   execute immediate 'select ' || seq_name || '.nextval from dual' into next_seq;
   return next_seq
END auto_increment;

-- In trigger code
...
if inserting then
  if :new.id is null then
    :new.id := auto_increment('myseq');
  end if;
end if;
...
```

Best way would be just embedding the sequence invocation in the `INSERT` statement. I would only use triggers if `INSERT` statements cannot be modified (maybe they are part of some 3rd party software that assumes that every DB in the world supports autoincrement columns).